# Combining NSFetchedResultsController with UITableView "insertion control"

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, insertion

I'm trying to get a UITableView to work with Core Data using an NSFetchedResultsController, while also having an insertion control (`UITableViewCellStyleInsert`) as the last row during editing.

Since the insertion control is just another tableviewcell, just with a different editing style, I have changed the appropriate UITableViewDatasource delegate methods, like:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
          editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self isInsertionControl:indexPath]) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```

The reported number of rows should also be updated accordingly, when editing (*assuming there's only one section for now*):

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];

    NSUInteger numberOfObjects = sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;

    // FIXME, things will go out of hand with more than one section.
    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        return numberOfObjects + 1;
    } else {
        return numberOfObjects;
    }
}
```

And if requested, return the appropriate cell for the insertion row:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = nil;

    if ([self isInsertionControl:indexPath]) {
        static NSString *InsertIdentifier = @"InsertCell";
        tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:InsertIdentifier
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    } else {
        tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [self configureCell:tableViewCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

This doesn't work, can anybody help me find out why?

**QUICK EDIT**

To be clear, I have 2 prototype cells in my storyboard, one for the regular content and one for representing the insertion row, both with the appropriate reuse identifier.